# wordpress plugin with custom form fields and email

Tags: wordpress, push-notification

I am creating an insurance company website. I want a form where the user can fill in his details, such as name, email, premium start date and end date, etc. and the system will automatically send an email to those users who's premium end date has 1 month remaining.

Is there a plugin that will provide this specific capability or some other similar plugin that I could customize to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I use **Fast Secure Contact Form**
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/si-contact-form/
Very good plugin and very customizeble.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dropifi Contact Widget, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropifi-contact-widget/. It is highly customizable and offer intelligent rules for automating tasks. You will not touch code to achieve all of this.